# how to query hasBelongsToMany Relationships in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm kinda stuck in between my flow and need your insights, I have tables users and tblRelations for maintaining friends of an user and for maintaining the relationships between them I've used hasBelongsToMany now when I'm querying it I'm getting a blank array of friends.
Question where I have gone wrong?

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey= 'userId';
protected $fillable = [
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'nickName',
    'email',
    'password',
    'profilePic',
    'phoneNumber',
    'userHeight',
    'userWeight',
    'userVertical',
    'userSchool',
    'homeTownId',
    'cityId',
    'activationCode',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','tblRelations','userId','userId');
}
}
```

Inside UserController

```
 public function loadFriend(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $loadFriends = $user->friends()->where('friendStatus',2)->get();
    if(!$loadFriends) {
        $this->setMeta("200", "You have No Friends");
        $this->setData("friendList", $loadFriends);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $this->setMeta("200", "Friendlist send successfully");
    $this->setData("friendList", $loadFriends);
    return response()->json($this->setResponse());

}
```

Response

```
"meta": {
"code": "200",
"message": "Friendlist send successfully"
},
"data": {
"friendList": []
}
```

Relation Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Relation extends Model
{
protected $table = 'tblRelations';
protected $primaryKey= 'relationId';
protected $fillable = [
    'userId',
    'friendId',
    'friendStatus',
];
}
```

Users migrations

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('userId');
        $table->string('firstName');
        $table->string('lastName')->nullable();
        $table->string('nickName')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('profilePic')->nullable();
        $table->string('phoneNumber')->nullable();
        $table->double('userHeight')->nullable();
        $table->double('userWeight')->nullable();
        $table->double('userVertical')->nullable();
        $table->string('userSchool')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('homeTownId')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('cityId')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('homeCourtId')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('userStatus')->default(1)->comment('0 FOR INACTIVE 1 FOR ACTIVE');
        $table->unsignedInteger('activationCode')->default(1);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    //Foreign Keys
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('cityId')->references('cityId')->on('tblCities')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('homeTownId')->references('cityId')->on('tblCities')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('homeCourtId')->references('homeCourtId')->on('tblHomeCourts')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

tblRelations migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tblRelations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('relationId');
        $table->unsignedInteger('userId');
        $table->unsignedInteger('friendId')->comment('userId as friendId');
        $table->boolean('friendStatus')->default(2)->comment('1 FOR REQUEST SENT 2 FOR REQUEST ACCEPT 3 FOR UNFRIEND 4 FOR BLOCK');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('tblRelations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //Foreign Keys
        $table->foreign('userId')->references('userId')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('friendId')->references('userId')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: no one here to help me? :(

Comment: Be patient buddy SO is for free! What does the model for tblRelations look like? Try `dd($loadFriends)` before you run your if statement on it, it's passing your if statement for a reason.

Comment: I had nothing in that. just add fillables in tblRelations

Comment: dd is returning empty

Comment: It's often useful to share your full DB schema for the elements involved in the question.

Comment: What does emtpy mean? `null`? try dd(!!$loadFriends) it will give you the variables boolean value and might explain why the if statement is passing.

Comment: empty means nothing not even null, and dd(!!$loadFriends) returning true

Comment: If you're getting true, you must be returning something. Please add your model or migration for relations by editing your question, I can't understand your DB schema 100%

Comment: yeah gimme a sec

Comment: Take your time buddy

Comment: Mm.. see the edits bro

Comment: Shouldn't the `friends()` relation on `User` reference `friendId` on `tblRelations`? Not `userId`? It currently reads `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','tblRelations','userId','userId');`

Comment: Mm. well I get this thank you for your time I got the thing I need :)

Comment: Pleasure, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after lots of hecks I got what I want and there are couple of things need to resolve to get it here I'm posting it

Inside User Model I need to define relations for both fields because I have 2 foreign keys in tblRelations

```
public function friends() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'tblRelations', 'userId', 'friendId');
}

public function friendOf() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'tblRelations', 'friendId', 'userId');

}
```

Then inside UserController I need to write like this using eager loading in laravel :)

```
public function loadFriend(Request $request)
{
    $loadFriends = User::with(['friends'])->where('userId',$request->userId)->first();
    if(!$loadFriends) {
        $this->setMeta("200", "You have No Friends");
        $this->setData("friendList", $loadFriends);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $this->setMeta("200", "Friendlist send successfully");
    $this->setData("friendList", $loadFriends->friends);
    return response()->json($this->setResponse());
}
```